# Imports in python

Tags: python, pygame

Recently I downloaded a game off pydev and the imports for it look like this below.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

However I have only ever created games by calling the in this way.

```
import pygame
import player
import enemy
```

I have called in the class one by one.

What does the lines of code at the top do? does it call all of his classes in?

Comment: This question would belong to [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/), but I am afraid it does not seem like you even did [any basic research](http://www.google.com/?q=python+import).

Comment: @SamHocevar: as it is it would belong to SO, but now he is also asking what `pygame.locals` does, which belongs here. (even there he did no research, though)

Answer (score 1):

It imports all public objects from `pygame.locals` into your module, so that you can use them directly instead of having to refer to them as `pygame.locals.whatever`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what does locals mean exactly? like the classes?

Comment: @RichardGibbons: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html --> _This module contains various constants used by Pygame. Its contents are automatically placed in the pygame module namespace. However, an application can use pygame.locals to include only the Pygame constants with a 'from pygame.locals import *'._